# Estimate of Taylor remainder

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, taylor-expansion

I want to show that
$$ \left |e^{ix} - \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(ix)^k}{k!}\right | \le \min\left \{\frac{|x|^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}, \frac{2|x|^n}{n!} \right\}
$$

The left term in the minimum is just an estimated Lagrange remainder, but I don't know how to get the second one.

Comment: is that $t$ an $x$?

Comment: @NelsonVanegasA. Corrected now.

Comment: See Lemma 3.3.19 [here](https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf).

Comment: @ShiveringSoldier Perfect, it seems this is the book the lecture is taken from. Write an answer!

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm too busy rn $:($ Please consider self-answering.